# Finding a client making DNS requests through a proxy

Tags: domain-name-system, proxy

I'm trying to trace an issue that's driving me mad.

We are using Cisco Umbrella to provide our web content filtering. And I'm seeing several blocks for inappropriate/malware sites from one IP address, which I'm tasked with investigating. I turned on DNS debugging on our DNS server and I've found out it is an internal Artica proxy making the requests (which was set up years before I started).

I've exported the logs from the Artica proxy in the hope that I'd be able to locate the IP address of the client that requested the sites through it however there are none of the sites at all in the logs!

Does anyone have experience of Artica, or any other way that I can find the culprit device? I assume that I could possibly put something like wireshark infront of the proxy and look that way?

Thanks
Matt

Answer (score 0):

> I assume that I could possibly put something like wireshark infront of
>   the proxy and look that way?

If you have the chance to trace using wireshark / tcpdump, search for `X-Forwarded-For` Header in HTTP Stream. If you are lucky, the downstream proxy/proxies noted the client's IP address in there.